# Dynamically routing using routes from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an ASP.Net Core 5.0 project. It uses Razor pages, not MVC. What I need to be able to do is have the routing engine look at the URL and if it doesn't match a page, it needs to go into the database and see if the name is in the database. If it is, then it needs to go to a generic page.

So my database has user names in it:

```
|--------------|
|     Joey     |
|   Samantha   |
|     Doc      |
|--------------|
```

As an example, if I go to `https://www.example.com/Joey`, it should actually load the `/Pages/Users/Index.cshtml` page and serve that up.

Same thing if I go to `https://www.example.com/Doc`, it should also load the `/Pages/Users/Index.cshtml` page.

I found a ton of examples on how to do this using classic ASP.Net and MVC, but I can't seem to find any good examples using .NET Core and Razor Pages.

My gut is telling me that I need to add something to my startup file after `services.AddRazorPages();` and I need to make some kind of custom routing service. Can someone please point me to some good documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **Index.cshtml** page replace `@page` with `@page "/{name?}"`. So you should have something like below:

```
@page "/{name?}"
@model MyApplicationNamespace.Pages.IndexModel
```

After that change the **Index.cshtml.cs** like below:

```
public IActionResult OnGet(string name)
{
    // Here you check if name parameter given trough the URL an check with its existence in the database. if yes, then `return Page();`
    // Otherwise just redirect to the error page or something to let the user know what happened by using `return RedirectToPage("TheErrorPage");`
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but wouldn't this break my other routes? Since it's going to this page, checking the name and if it's not a match, going straight to an error page. I would think it would need to check the static routes first, then fallover to this route, then fallover to an error page. Is that correct? Again, I haven't tried this yet so it could be smart enough to just know that and work

Comment: With all solutions that are dealing with routes there is a risk to break some other routes. So it upon you to know exactly what kind of routes your application is dealing with.